# "cannot open file 'winmm.lib' even though I have Windows SDK installed (SFML Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, sfml, winmm

I'm trying to setup SFML on Visual Studio but I come across this error, everywhere I search tells me that I need to install the Windows SFK, but I did multiple times and even with that Visual Studio Installer thing and it never works...

If someone knows how to fix this I will be pretty happy to know ^-^

Comment: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=21958.0

Comment: I don't see how thats supposed to help at all?

Comment: It can help you in part, i think

Comment: Without any indication **when** your get this error and **the exact error message** there is little we can do for you.

Comment: I get it while compiling the project and the exact error is: "LNK1104 cannot open file 'winmm.lib'